# Start Powershell process with multiple line script as an argument

Tags: powershell, process, arguments

I'm trying to start powershell process with this command:

```
$command = @"
select volume = D
delete partition override
"@
$command | diskpart
```

When I paste it into Powershell it works but it doesn't when I'm trying to use it as an argument when starting Powershell process. How do I format the command for it to work? I tried using ' but It didn't help.

Comment: Please show us the exact process command line that's failing :)

Comment: Separate lines by semicolon or call `powershell.exe` with parameter `-EncodedCommand` to pass a base64-encoded command. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-encode-string-and-execute-with-powershell/

Comment: Did you try an underscore at end of line which is a continuation line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using -EncodedCommand and converting to base64 worked.